# Pytest reports test skipped with unittest.skip as passed

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

The test looks something like this:

```
import unittest

class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @unittest.skip
    def test_bar(self):
        self.assertIsNone('not none')
```

When run using `pytest`, the report looks something like:

```
path/to/my/tests/test.py::FooTestCase::test_bar <- ../../../../../usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py PASSED
```

On the other hand, if I replace `@unittest.skip` with `@pytest.mark.skip`, it is properly reported as skipped:

```
path/to/my/tests/test.py::FooTestCase::test_bar <- ../../../../../usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py SKIPPED
```

If anyone could say, am I doing something wrong or is that a bug in `pytest`?

Comment: Looks like you need to call `unittest.skip`. Try `@unittest.skip(<something>)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`unittest.skip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.skip) decorator requires an argument:

> `@unittest.skip(reason)`
>
> Unconditionally skip the decorated test. *reason* should describe why
>   the test is being skipped.

Its usage is found in their [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures):

> ```
> class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
>
>     @unittest.skip("demonstrating skipping")
>     def test_nothing(self):
>         self.fail("shouldn't happen")
> ```

Thus `unittest.skip` is not a decorator by itself, but a decorator factory - the actual decorator is obtained as a result of calling `unittest.skip`.

This explains why your test passes instead of being skipped or failing, since it is actually equivalent to the following:

```
import unittest

class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_bar(self):
        self.assertIsNone('not none')

    test_bar = unittest.skip(test_bar)
    # now test_bar becomes a decorator but is instead invoked by
    # pytest as if it were a unittest method and passes
```

Comment: Hi, could you please tell how can I prevent `skip()`, `skipIf()` method from escaping the `reason` string. The problem is the output of the `skip()` or `skipIf()` decorator is joined at `\n` which I don't want. Please enlighten me!

Comment: @Ayush Why don't you post a question about it?

Comment: My relations with stackoverflow are not so good, community hate when I ask questions on stackoverflow... Okay, I'm banned from asking more questions could you please tell me if something like that is even possible?